# Google Scripts in Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to have a spreadsheet in Google Drive where the script is protected from modification / editing? Does anyone know if that is an option in the Script editor?

Another thing I'd like to ask. How does one do source control for the codes in their Google scripts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WRT privacy / protection of scripts: Refer to the comments and answers on this question: [How to protect the Apps Script code in a Google spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075446/how-to-protect-the-google-app-script-code-in-google-spreadsheet).

Source Control? See [Backing up Gapps source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14385008/backing-up-gapps-source). The version tracking in the script editor is rudimentary, so you should consider doing source control outside - you'll have to get used to copy & paste.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't do it.

The script runs with the document permissions.

If you have Edit permissions on the document, you have edit permission on the script too.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the Google spreadsheet developer guide.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/

Comment: Those are the script reference. But does not provide any guidance on locking the scripts.